# How to convert plain text to html format in mac

Tags: macos, cocoa

How to convert plain text of text field/view to html format.

For Eg.: 
  Plain text -> 
    Welcome to my new Page.
    This my second line.

HTML text:-
      Plain text with html tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text Editor which converts text into HTML format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274803/text-editor-which-converts-text-into-html-format)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in `<pre>` ... `</pre>`.

Comment: Need some Text Editor which convert normal text in to html