# Text Editor which converts text into HTML format

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am looking for an editor in mac osx. Which help me to pragmatically convert normal plain text in to HTML format.

Thanks

Comment: You want to create or want an already created one?

Comment: Who will add AI to it? how will it know which one is H1, h3, <br>, <p> <li> etc?

Comment: mardown to html using a tool on osx, this belongs on superuser and if offtopic

Comment: in his comment to my answer, he indicated he needed a library for his own app

Answer (score 0):

dont really follow. plain text doesn't contain any formatting so what's for html to add?

if you just to display text on webpage:

EITHER wrap it in **< pre >BLABLA< / pre >**
OR do a search and replace of **all line endings** with **a < br / > line ending**

=> no specific editor for that. if you want to convert markdown to html, there are some... I like markdown pro

---

for C / objC (osx and iOS both) use the lib Sundown :: https://github.com/Daij-Djan/sundown [originally for C, I added an easy objC wrapper]

Comment: Please see stack overflow editor. There is html button which convert plain text into html format. Same thing i want to do programmatically.

Comment: no that called MARKDOWN and I wrote you the name for an editor for OSX :)

Comment: Thanks to reply, I saw MARKDOWN editor, but how can i implement it in application or how can i get source code/framework of MARKDOWN to implement it in application.

Comment: sundown is nice but I guess there are others too!

Comment: Here's a Markdown library for Objective-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435288/what-is-the-simplest-implementation-of-markdown-for-a-cocoa-application

Answer (score 0):

Kwrite and Kate (KDE text editor and KDE advanced text editor) will do that for you. As they're part of KDE you will have to install them using [one of the methods outlined here](http://community.kde.org/Mac).

Create or copy some text then:-
toolbar => File => Export as HTML

Comment: Thanks to reply, but how can i implement it in application ? or how can i get source code/framework of MARKDOWN to implement it in application?.